# Gatsby: Re-execute page queries manually

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, headless, craftcms

Do you know if it's possible to re-execute Gatsby page queries (normal queries) manually?
Note, This should happen in dev mode while `gatsby develop` runs.

Background info: I'm trying to set up a draft environment with Gatsby and a Headless CMS (Craft CMS in my case). I want `gatsby develop` to run on, say, heroku. The CMS requests a Gatsby page, passing a specific draft-token as an URL param, and then the page queries should be re-executed, using the token to re-fetch the draft content from the CMS rather than the published content.

I'm hooking into the token-request via a middleware defined in `gatsby-config.js`. This is all based on https://gist.github.com/monachilada/af7e92a86e0d27ba47a8597ac4e4b105

I tried

```js
createSchemaCustomization({ refresh: true }).then(() => {
  sourceNodes()
})
```

but this completely re-creates all pages. I really only want the page queries to be extracted/executed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#reserved-environment-variables). Basically, you need to set an environment variable (`ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT`) which opens and exposes a `/__refresh` webhook that is able to receive `POST` requests to refresh the sourced content. This exposed webhook can be triggered whenever remote data changes, which means you can update your data without re-launching the development server.

You can also trigger it manually using: `curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh`

If you need a detailed explanation of how to set `.env` variables in Gatsby just tell me and I will provide a detailed explanation. But you just need to create a `.env` file with your variables (`ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT=true`) and place this snippet in your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${activeEnv}`,
})
```

Of course, it will only work under the development environment but in this case, it fits your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried the refresh endpoint before, but this also rebuilds all pages while I only want the page queries to be rebuilt, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild for all is needed f.e. when you have indexing pages.

It looks like you need some logic to conditionally call `createPage` (with all data refetched) or even conditionally fetch data for selected pages only.

If amount (of pages) is relatively not so big I would fetch for all data to get page update times. Then in loop conditionally (time within a few minutes - no needs to pass parameter) call `createPage`.

If develop doesn't call 'createPage' on `/__refresh` ... dive deeper into gatsby code and find logic and way to modify redux `touched` nodes.

... or search for other optimization techniques you can use for this scenario (queried data cached into json files?).